# How do I get date & time in a different time zone?

Tags: java, time, timezone

I am using Indigo Service Release 2. I have written following code:

```
TimeZone calcutta = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
Date now = new Date(); 
DateFormat format = 
    DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL);  
format.setTimeZone(calcutta);  
jlabel_IndiaTime.setText((format.format(now).toString()));
```

It is showing `Monday, September 17,2012 1:13:23 PM IST`, but in India the time is 10:14AM. I am trying this from New York. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal : Not C#. I am writing code in JAVA.

Comment: What do you get when you print out `Timezone.getDefault()`?

Comment: Your code works from the command line (my default timezone is "America/Denver"). I'd file it as an eclipse bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code.  I'm explicitly setting my server's default time zone to NY time, but you may want to follow Jon Lin's hint and determine for certain the default time zone of your own server.  For example, if you're in NY, but are using a server hosted in SF and using Pacific time, then that could account for a 3 hour difference from the expected time in any zone.

```
public void testTodayInIndia() {
    // For demonstration, make my system act as though it's in New York
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    long oneDay = 86400000;
    long fourYears = (365 * 4 + 1) * oneDay;
    // Calculate 42 years after 1/1/1970 UTC
    Date now = new Date(fourYears * 10 + oneDay * 365 * 2 + 1);
    TimeZone calcutta = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    // Since unspecified, this output will show the date and time in New York
    assertEquals("2011-12-31 19:00:00", formatter.format(now));
    // After setting the formatter's time zone, output reflects the same instant in Calcutta.
    formatter.setTimeZone(calcutta);
    assertEquals("2012-01-01 05:30:00", formatter.format(now));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat and Date classes such as below:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
```

There are different time zones you can replace with "America/New_York" such "Asia/Calcutta".